# Why Unity3D Use Monodevelop(4.0.1) not the latest Xamarin(5.9)

Tags: unity-game-engine, xamarin, ide, monodevelop

I use Unity 4.6.3 and Monovelop 4 is installed by default. It seems Monodevelop 4 has many bugs.

I see the lastest Monovelop is Xamarin(5.9) http://www.monodevelop.com/download/. 
Why Unity did't use Xamarin as its default IDE?

If I want to use Xamarin as Unity's default IDE , do you have some tips or document for me.

By the way, I know I can change the default IDE by Edit=>Preferences=>External Tools=>External Script Editor. I just confuse why unity did't use the latest monodevelop?

Comment: I suspect the reason is that Unity wanted to ship a _known quantity_ of Monodevelop - one they know they have tested and shown to be compatible; and to limit somewhat what versions of .NET projects can be created.    The same pattern is undertaken with the commercial product Ranorex and the open source SharpDevelop on which it is based.

Comment: @MickyDuncan it seems reasonable. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You're totally right, I've been working with this old and buggy MonoDevelop version way too long.

But there didn't seem to be a real alternative, at least until last week a colleague of mine found some nice Add-Ins, that make Xamarin 5.9 working quite well with Unity.

**Note:**
This only works for Unity starting from **4.6.5p2**. 
But I'd recommend to update Unity to the latest version anyway, as there are a lot of bugfixes (especially for IL2CPP, if you're doing iOS).

### Add-Ins

The Xamarin Add-Ins can be found here: http://files.unity3d.com/lukasz/Unity-Addins-5.9.0.zip

### Requirements

- Xamarin 5.9: http://www.monodevelop.com/download
- Unity 4.6.5p2 or above:

  - releases: http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
  - patch releases: http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

### Installation

- Unpack the zip file. You will now have 4 files with an .mpack extension.
- Open MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio.
- Open Add-In Manager

  - OS X: Xamarin Studio ➔ Add-in Manager.
  - Windows: Tools ➔ Add-in Manager
- Click "Install from file" and select the 4 .mpack files.
- Restart MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio.
- You should now be able open, build and debug any Unity generated solution/projects.

### Make it the default Script Editor in Unity

- Open Unity
- Go to Preferences (OS X: `CMD + ,`)
- External Tools ➔ External Script Editor
- Use `Browse` to select your Xamarin installation

### Source

The complete guide can be found here:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-add-ins-for-monodevelop-xamarin-studio-5-9.329880/

Answer (score 0):

you can just set it as default editor. Edit=>Preferences=>External Tools=>External Script Editor

Comment: I know this. I just confuse why unity did't use the lastest monodevelop? By the way, do you use Xamarin to develop Unity?

Answer (score 0):

What's problematic is that you can open CSharp Projects in it, but when you have UnityScript projects in your Solution file it won't open correctly in Xamarin. It says could not load project "Your project.unityproj". So Assembly-CSharp* works, but not Assembly-UnityScript*.

That's the reason I can think of so far!

Comment: Negative vote for no reason! The first paragraph explains why they shouldn't use Xamarin as the editor. The question is answered. If you have strictly c# then you should be fine, but if you have unityscript files then it's problematic. Personally I use SulbimeText with custom loggers, and build systems! Also you can load snippet add ins, and completions add ins.